# How to tell if homebrew is installed on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, homebrew

I am doing some Rails programming and I consistently see Homebrew referenced in solutions around the web but have never used it.

I also notice Homebrew in the terminal version 2.9 as an option next to "Shell -> New" from the terminal drop down but when I select homebrew and issue commands, they fail.

Usually with the "command not found" error.

Strangely enough I have been unable to locate a simple command to determine whether brew is installed or not.

How do I check to see if Homebrew is already installed on my Mac?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

`brew help`. If brew is there, you get output. If not, you get 'command not found'. If you need to check in a script, you can work out how to redirect output and check `$?`.

Comment: I executed "brew help"and got nothing. I decided to just go ahead with the install and now "brew help" returns results. Thanks.

Comment: `brew -v` prints the `Homebrew` version

Comment: paste it to your command: /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Answer (score 70):

I use this to perform update or install:

```
which -s brew
if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then
    # Install Homebrew
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
else
    brew update
fi
```

Comment: Very great solution to installing packages if they're not found!

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh

Answer (score 68):

The standard way of figuring out if something is installed is to use `which`.

If Brew is installed.

```
>>> which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

If Brew is not installed.

```
>>> which brew
brew not found
```

> Note: The "not installed" message depends on your shell. `zsh` is shown above. `bash` will just not print anything. `csh` will say `brew: Command not found.` In the "installed" case, all shells will print the path.)

It works with all command line programs. Try `which grep` or `which python`. Since it tells you the program that you're running, it's helpful when debugging as well.

Comment: I am not getting anything when i wrote which brew on my mac machine terminal

Comment: Depending on which shell you use, you'll get different messages. That's a good clarification!

Answer (score 44):

While `which` is the most common way of checking if a program is installed, it will tell you a program is installed ONLY if it's in the `$PATH`. So if your program is installed, but the `$PATH` wasn't updated for whatever reason*, `which` will tell you the program isn't installed.

(*One example scenario is changing from Bash to Zshell and `~/.zshrc` not having the old `$PATH` from `~/.bash_profile`)

`command -v foo` is a better alternative to `which foo`. `command -v brew` will output nothing if Homebrew is not installed

```bash
command -v brew
```

Here's a sample script to check if Homebrew is installed, install it if it isn't, update if it is.

```bash
if [[ $(command -v brew) == "" ]]; then
    echo "Installing Hombrew"
    /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
else
    echo "Updating Homebrew"
    brew update
fi
```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks for posting alternative to which and an explanation.

Comment: From the Bash manual, in the description of `command`: "Only builtin commands or commands found in the PATH are executed". So `command`, just as `which`, uses `PATH` (which makes sense: it needs to know where to look for). I have Homebrew installed on my computer but I broke my `PATH` and neither `which` nor `command` are able to find it.

Comment: are you sure about that? as per the POSIX manual, it seems that `command` can find shell functions and aliases and shell reserved words, not just built-in or special utilities https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/command.1p.html

Answer (score 21):

`brew -v` or `brew --version` does the trick!

Answer (score 13):

I just type brew -v in terminal if you have it it will respond with the version number installed.

Answer (score 11):

Location of the brew where it installed

```
which brew
```

version of home brew install

```
brew --version
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe your mac don't received the path

[Terminal Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iQH3.png)

Run command below

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

And run to check that work
`brew help`

Comment: Thank you - my brew disappeared after changing default shell to bash. This is the only solution that worked!

Comment: I'm very happy to help you !!

Answer (score 5):

```
[ ! -f "`which brew`" ] && echo "not installed"
```

Explaination: If brew is not installed run command after `&&`

Answer (score 4):

Beginners normally do, the `homebrew --version` which is wrong.

Do instead, `brew --version`. `brew help` works also. If these two commands are not executed, you don't have homebrew installed.

Answer (score 3):

`brew doctor` checks if Homebrew is installed and working properly.

Answer (score 2):

use either the `which` or `type` built-in tools.

i.e.: `which brew` or `type brew`

Answer (score 2):

jest write `brew -v` in terminal and if you have it , you will see there version number and the install date  .
like this :
Homebrew 3.3.12
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision c3cacc9cd1d; last commit 2022-01-31)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision fb6ec06d8b; last commit 2022-01-31)

Answer (score 1):

Another one possible way:

```
# Check if Ninja is installed
if ! which ninja > /dev/null
then
echo 'Ninja installation...'
brew install ninja
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6

```
brew -v

OutPut-
Homebrew 2.2.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 71aa; last commit 2020-01-07)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 84f00; last commit 2020-01-07)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run `which brew`, but you may have it installed and it says it is not found if you are using zsh. You will need to add it to your .zshrc file.

Answer (score 1):

I find it simple to use **brew help** command to find it is installed or not. There was a user guide on the homebrew download page.

If it is not installed then it will show **'command not found'**

If you need to install homebrew then paste this on terminal:

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using the "command" builtin tool

```sh
if [ "$(command -v brew)" ]; then
    echo "command \"brew\" exists on system"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you install Homebrew, type command **brew doctor** in terminal.

- If you get the following message:

  > **Your system is ready to brew**

  then you are good to go and you have successfully installed homebrew.
- If you get any warnings, you can try fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal, do `which brew` and itll tell you where it was installed at within your computer, but itll only work in zsh not in bash.

Answer (score -1):

Running Catalina 10.15.4 I ran the permissions command below to get brew to install

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* && sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
```